# I can't fetch XML data via fetch API - blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, fetch-api

I try to fetch data from URL link in VUE, the link response XML data in the browser but, when I try to retrieve the data in the code I get
CORS error:

```js
fetch(
  'https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Datasets/yield.xml',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    },
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.text();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');
    console.log(xml);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ElyA.jpg)

Comment: If the target site does not explicitly want to allow access from pages served by different domains, there's nothing you can do other than implement a proxy of your own.

Comment: Or use a third party cors proxy service of which there are several